# Oracle Apex - Import xlsx file in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

We are using Oracle Apex 4.2.5 version.

I know we have a capability to import .csv files and I tried, and it works fine.

Now, I have one more requirement where I want to import :

a) .xlsx (excel) file

b) multiple tab .xlsx (excel) file at once using import.

Could you please confirm if this can be achieved in Oracle apex ?

Answer (score 0):

It *can* but not with an APEX release that dates back to 2014 :-)

If you upgrade to any supported version of APEX you get XLSX handling natively in the app.

If you really can't upgrade (?) then check out Jeff Kemp's post on various options you can explore

https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2018/11/load-spreadsheet-data-into-apex/

But really ... its time to upgrade!

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your response! Could you please confirm if we have the feature of Multi-tab excel upload in new oracle apex version (Single excel file with multiple tabs in it) or can we not achieve it using Oracle apex. If not, can you suggest any alternative to consume multi -tab files?

Comment: Yes - check out the APEX_DATA_PARDER package (which is what APEX is using under the covers) https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex-data-parser-package

Answer (score 0):

1. On the matter of support for XLSX file uploads

> The APEX_DATA_PARSER PL/SQL package was introduced in APEX 19.1.
> [https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/apex-data-parser-data-load-made-easy#:~:text=The%20APEX_DATA_PARSER%20PL%2FSQL%20package,by%20the%20APEX%20development%20team](https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/apex-data-parser-data-load-made-easy#:%7E:text=The%20APEX_DATA_PARSER%20PL%2FSQL%20package,by%20the%20APEX%20development%20team).

2. You definitely can handle multiple tabs inside a spreadsheet after uploading

Under the APEX_DATA_PARSER package there is a function called GET_XLSX_WORKSHEETS function that you could use:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/GET_XLSX_WORKSHEETS-Function.html#GUID-41FC640A-A683-440E-A8F4-026BDD582C34